# How to convert image to hex or string in visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

We have an  image file to be tranfered to the microprocessor via Serial Communicaton. What we want to do is to transfer this image file to hex document so that this microprocessor can view this hex document on its Lcd. How can i transfer this image file to an hex document? We are new in visual C++. Thus, please be specific as much as possible:)
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to be more specific on your question on the other hand. `.bmp` can be named a hex document; it can mean any binary file. What are the input formats you want to use? What's the desired output format?

Comment: I mean with the hex document, an output which contains hex of the image that is loaded. Actually, i have found a program which is called as "İmg2Hex" in a google search and i want to do the same thing in Visual C++.

Comment: If you mean ASCII hex, that would be a very poor comms protocol for bulk-binaries like images or video.  it's not hard to convert binaries to ASCII hex strings, but you must be prepared for very slow transfer.